# Select statement with textboxes and checkboxes in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to build a query that will allow me to search via text box and check box at the same time , but am getting a returned value of no record each time and cannot determine why.

```
con.Open();

string str = "Select * from engineering where Education = @Education AND JobNumber like '%' + @search + '%'  ";

SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str.ToString(), con);

xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtProjectNumber.Text;
xp.Parameters.Add("@Education", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkEducational.CheckState;

try 
{
    da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = xp;
    da.Fill(ss);
    Showdata(pos);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "ss");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];
} 
catch 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");
}

con.Close();
```

above is the code to my search button. There is no need to worry about the Showdata(pos) because that is there only to scroll through the returned results. The query will work if I take out the Education = @Education , or JobNumber = '%' + @search1 + '%' , just not together for some reason. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us why there aren't any records in your table (which we've never seen) where some column whose contents we can't guess at is equal to some value you've kept a tightly guarded secret, *and* some other mystery column matchs some other value known only to you and the NSA. And the answer is, find out what is actually going in `@Education` and `@search`, and what values are in those respective columns.

Comment: Here's a question for you: This expression keeps returning false: `stuff.Any(f)` Can you show me where in my code the problem is? Or it might be in my database, unless I got the data from a webservice (I forget). Thanks!

Comment: on the database side , jobnumber is varchar and Education is int (1 for checked , 0 for unchecked). So if I were to just check the checkbox and leave the textbox blank , I would hope to return all records that have 1 in that field in the database , however if I were to type a number into that text field and check the checkbox , I would like to return the records that have that specific job number and check box checked.

Comment: Have you tested that SQL directly in your SQL environment? If it works with one parameter *or* the other, most likely there just aren't any records where both are true.

Comment: Yes , I have run the query within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and have gotten the record I was looking for. Also even if I just type a jobnumber in the textbox  and do not check the checkbox , I am getting no record found. I am unable to retrieve any record with this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out an answer as to what I wanted to happen , I wrote the query as normal with the text box parameters and added an if statement that added to the where clause if the check box was checked .

Here is an example of what I am talking about :

```
con.Open();


        string str = "select * from engineering where JobNumber like '%' + @search + '%' ";
if(chkEducational.Checked)
str += "AND Education = @Education";

SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str.ToString(), con);


 xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =  txtProjectNumber.Text;
xp.Parameters.Add("@Education", SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkEducational.CheckState;



try
        {


            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = xp;
            da.Fill(ss);
            Showdata(pos);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "ss");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["ss"];

        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Record Found");

        }





        con.Close();
```

Thank you to those who took the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "Select * from engineering where Education = @Education AND JobNumber like @search";    
SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str.ToString(), con);      
xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "%" + txtProjectNumber.Text + "%";
```

Comment: when executing , I still get the no records found message.